# Парсер HTML в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла необходимость получить данные из отчета рабочей программы, отчет в HTML.

Собственно HTML документ(Выкладываю только блок где находятся необходимые данные, если нужно дополнительно залью весь файл):

```
<tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">РАЗМЕРЫ:&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom"><fontsize="2">377.000&nbsp;x&nbsp;77.000&nbsp;mm&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ПОВЕРХНОСТЬ:&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom"><font size="2">29029.00&nbsp;mm2&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ИМЯ СВОДА ПРАВИЛ:&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="top"><font size="2">5P&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">НОМЕР ПОДПРОГРАММЫ:&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="top"><font size="2">SP1DOR_SHEST_BR6 / SP3DOR_SHEST_BR6&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ВРЕМЯ ОБРАБОТКИ:&nbsp;</font></td>
```

Установил модуль Beautiful Soup, немного почитал документацию и написал следующий скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('File1.HTML', 'rb')
doc = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
rez = []
for x in soup.find_all('font', size="2"):
    rez.append(x.contents[0])
    if x.contents[0] == 'ВЕС: ':  #Велосипед для ограничения выхода из диапазона
        break
inp = []
for y in range(1000):
    if str(rez[y]) == 'НОМЕР ЧЕРТЕЖА: ':
        inp.append([rez[y], rez[y+1]])
print(inp)
```

Очень всё шатко, и ограничение по циклу, будет работать если у меня отчет на одно изделие. Идея в том, что получить данные из всех font, затем прогнать результат в цикле и найти с помощью If-ов необходимые данные, для примера допустим нужно извлечь поле "РАЗМЕРЫ: " и соответственно значение этого поля "377.000 x 77.000 mm ".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сомнительный результат, поэтому не могли бы вы подсказать как это лучше реализовать?

Полный HTML файл(оформлен ужасно):

```
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!--


  $Revision:   1.0  $
  $Date:   11 Apr 2011 14:28:48  $
  All rights reserved to Trumpf GmbH + Co. KG, Germany


WICHTIG:
Hinweis fuer die Ansicht mit Microsoft Word !!
Wenn Sie diesen Text lesen koennen, dann muessen Sie im Word
die Ansicht ALLER nichtdruckbaren Zeichen deaktivieren im Menue
"Extras - Optionen" auf der Karteikarte "Ansicht"


IMPORTANT:
Note for use with Microsoft Word!!
If you can read this text, you should deactivate the view of not printable characters
in the menu
"extra - options" on folder "view"!


//-->


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>
   TruTops Laser - ПЛАН НАЛАДКИ /
   TruLaser 3030 (L20) -
   1 /
   DOR_SHEST_BR6
</title>
<meta name="author" content="Antonov" />
<meta name="keywords" content="L20,
ТИП:1, Technika" />
</head>
<!--body bgcolor="#D0D0D0"-->
<body link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080">
<basefont face="Arial" size="1" />


<!--HTML-Block: Indizierungsblock -->
<!--Dieser Block wird von der ToPs-Teileverwaltung geparst-->
<!--
[INFO_TV]
Maschine="L20"
truMachineName="TruLaser 3030 (L20)"
Steuerung="Sin 840D"
Firma="Technika"
Benutzer="Antonov"
Erstelldatum="25.08.2015"
Auftragsname=" "
NC_Datei="D:\эксперемент\Проба длина реза\DOR_SHEST_BR6.LST"
Material="St37-80"
Lagergut="ST000800----0660x0400"
MetrischInch="1"
TafelX="660.00"
TafelY="400.00"
TafelZ="8.00"
[ENDE]
//-->


<!--HTML-Block: Programm-Barcode-->


<!--HTML-Block: Firmenkopf (mit Logo)-->
<!--Firmenlogo-->
<table width="600" border="0" rules="none" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" width="10%">
         <img src="E:/Templates/HTML/SYSTEM_Logo.gif" alt="E:/Templates/HTML/SYSTEM_Logo.gif" />
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" width="70%">
         <!--Ueberschrift fuer allgemeine Daten-->
         <font size="4"><b>ПЛАН НАЛАДКИ<br />ОБЩИЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ&nbsp;</b></font>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" width="20%">
         <font size="2">
         &#65;&#110;&#116;&#111;&#110;&#111;&#118;&nbsp;
         <br />
         25.08.2015
         <br />
         TruTops Laser
         V10.00.00
         </font>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>


<!--HTML-Block: allgemeine Einrichteplan-Informationen-->


<!--HTML-Block: Fertigungsanweisungen fuer LaserOnly-->


<!--HTML-Block: Fertigungsanweisungen fuer Wasserstrahl-->


<!--HTML-Block: Lasertab.-Liste-->


<!--HTML-Block: Wassertab.-Detail-Liste-->


<!--HTML-Block: Lasertab.-Detail-Liste-->


<!--HTML-Block: Einzelteile als Liste-->


<!--HTML-Block: Einzelteil-Informationen mit Grafiken, ohne Barcode -->


<!--HTML-Block: Einzelteil-Informationen mit Grafiken, mit Barcode -->


<!--HTML-Block: Einzelteil-Informationen ohne Grafiken-->
<!--START Einzelteilinformationen-->
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left">
         <!--Ueberschrift Einzelteilinformationen-->
         <font size="4"><b>ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ОБ ОТД. ДЕТАЛИ&nbsp;</b></font>
      </td>
   </tr>
<tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">НОМЕР ДЕТАЛИ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">1&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">НОМЕР ЧЕРТЕЖА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">425900-92.08.101&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ИМЯ ЧЕРТЕЖА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">   ЗАКАЗЧИКА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">КОЛИЧЕСТВО:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">4&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">РАЗМЕРЫ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">377.000&nbsp;x&nbsp;77.000&nbsp;mm&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ПОВЕРХНОСТЬ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">29029.00&nbsp;mm2&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ИМЯ СВОДА ПРАВИЛ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">5P&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">НОМЕР ПОДПРОГРАММЫ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">SP1DOR_SHEST_BR6 / SP3DOR_SHEST_BR6&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ВРЕМЯ ОБРАБОТКИ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">0.47 min (PierceLine: 0.47 min)&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ДЛИНА РЕЗКИ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">1241.13&nbsp;mm&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ВЕС:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">1.823&nbsp;kg&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">КОЛ-ВО ТОЧЕК ВРЕЗАНИЯ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">1&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ВРЕМЯ ВРЕЗАНИЯ&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">0.17 (PierceLine: 0.06)&nbsp;s&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ИМЯ ГЕОМ. ФАЙЛА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">D:\Programs TRUMPF\2015\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 (доп.1)\Крой ч10\425900-92.08.101.GEO&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ПРЕДВ. НАЧЕРЧ. РАЗМЕТКА:</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">SP1DOR_SHEST_BR6 - 0.13 min</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">НОМЕР ДЕТАЛИ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">2&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">НОМЕР ЧЕРТЕЖА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">425900-92.08.102&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ИМЯ ЧЕРТЕЖА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">   ЗАКАЗЧИКА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">КОЛИЧЕСТВО:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">4&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">РАЗМЕРЫ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">264.000&nbsp;x&nbsp;77.000&nbsp;mm&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ПОВЕРХНОСТЬ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">20328.00&nbsp;mm2&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ИМЯ СВОДА ПРАВИЛ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">5P&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">НОМЕР ПОДПРОГРАММЫ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">SP2DOR_SHEST_BR6 / SP4DOR_SHEST_BR6&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ВРЕМЯ ОБРАБОТКИ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">0.42 min (PierceLine: 0.42 min)&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ДЛИНА РЕЗКИ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">1023.53&nbsp;mm&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">ВЕС:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="bottom"><font size="2">1.277&nbsp;kg&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">КОЛ-ВО ТОЧЕК ВРЕЗАНИЯ:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">1&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ВРЕМЯ ВРЕЗАНИЯ&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">0.17 (PierceLine: 0.06)&nbsp;s&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ИМЯ ГЕОМ. ФАЙЛА:&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">D:\Programs TRUMPF\2015\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 (доп.1)\Крой ч10\425900-92.08.102.GEO&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">ПРЕДВ. НАЧЕРЧ. РАЗМЕТКА:</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">SP2DOR_SHEST_BR6 - 0.15 min</font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2"></font></td></tr>

</table>
<!--ENDE Einzelteilinformationen-->
<br />


<!--HTML-Block: Tafellayout-->


<br />

<!--HTML-Block: Palettierungsgrafik-->


<!--HTML-Block: TRUMPF-Zeitberechnung-->
<!--
<ZEITSTUDIE>
   <BASIS_DATA>
      <TOPS>TruTops Laser</TOPS>
      <LOGO>E:/Templates/HTML/SYSTEM_Logo.gif</LOGO>
      <FIRMA>Technika</FIRMA>
      <USER>Antonov</USER>
      <DATUM>25.08.2015</DATUM>
      <MASCHINENZEIT>3.68</MASCHINENZEIT>
      <TAFELLAYOUT>TMT_DOR_SHEST_BR6.BMP</TAFELLAYOUT>
      <LST_NAME>D:\эксперемент\Проба длина реза\DOR_SHEST_BR6.LST</LST_NAME>
      <EPLAN_NAME>D:\эксперемент\Проба длина реза\DOR_SHEST_BR6.HTML</EPLAN_NAME>
      <UNIT>0</UNIT>
      <LASERGESAMTSCHNITTLAENGE>9058.63</LASERGESAMTSCHNITTLAENGE>
   </BASIS_DATA>
   <MACHINE_DATA>
      <MASCHINE>L20</MASCHINE>
      <ARBBER>3000.0 x 1500.0 mm</ARBBER>
      <LASERLEISTUNG>6000</LASERLEISTUNG>
   </MACHINE_DATA>
   <MATERIAL_DATA>
      <MATERIAL>St37-80</MATERIAL>
      <MASS_X>660.00</MASS_X>
      <MASS_Y>400.00</MASS_Y>
      <MASS_Z>8.00</MASS_Z>
      <VERSCHNITT>25.22</VERSCHNITT>
   </MATERIAL_DATA>
   <EINZELTEIL_DATA>
      <EINZELTEIL_SET><ZEICHN_NAME></ZEICHN_NAME><ZEICHN_NUMMER>425900-92.08.101</ZEICHN_NUMMER><ANZAHL>4</ANZAHL><EINZELTEILZEIT>0.48</EINZELTEILZEIT><DATEINAME>D:\Programs TRUMPF\2015\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 (доп.1)\Крой ч10\425900-92.08.101.GEO</DATEINAME><GRAFIK>DOR_SHEST_BR6_425900-92.08.101_1.BMP</GRAFIK><LASERSCHNITTLAENGE>1241.13</LASERSCHNITTLAENGE></EINZELTEIL_SET>
      <EINZELTEIL_SET><ZEICHN_NAME></ZEICHN_NAME><ZEICHN_NUMMER>425900-92.08.102</ZEICHN_NUMMER><ANZAHL>4</ANZAHL><EINZELTEILZEIT>0.42</EINZELTEILZEIT><DATEINAME>D:\Programs TRUMPF\2015\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 (доп.1)\Крой ч10\425900-92.08.102.GEO</DATEINAME><GRAFIK>DOR_SHEST_BR6_425900-92.08.102_2.BMP</GRAFIK><LASERSCHNITTLAENGE>1023.53</LASERSCHNITTLAENGE></EINZELTEIL_SET>

   </EINZELTEIL_DATA>
   <WZG_DATA>
      <WZG_SET><WZG_TYP>99</WZG_TYP><WZG_MASS1>Laser 6000W</WZG_MASS1></WZG_SET>

   </WZG_DATA>
</ZEITSTUDIE>
//-->


<!--SQL-Statements fuer Etikettendruck-->
<!--
<sqlexecute>
<sql>CREATE TABLE LabelSheetData</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN Count COUNTER PRIMARY KEY</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN Processed INT</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN ProgramNumber VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN ProgramName VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN ProgramRemark VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN ProgramRuns VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN MachineName VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN MachineType VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN Control VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN Company VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN JobName VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN MaterialId VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN SheetSizeX VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN SheetSizeY VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN SheetSizeZ VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN TubeProfile VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN TubeDimensionLabel VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN TubeDimension VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelSheetData ADD COLUMN SheetWeight VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>INSERT INTO LabelSheetData
(
Processed,
ProgramNumber,
ProgramName,
ProgramRemark,
ProgramRuns,
MachineName,
MachineType,
Control,
Company,
JobName,
MaterialId,
SheetSizeX,
SheetSizeY,
SheetSizeZ,
TubeProfile,
TubeDimensionLabel,
TubeDimension,
SheetWeight
) VALUES 
(
0,
'DOR_SHEST_BR6',
'D:\эксперемент\Проба длина реза\DOR_SHEST_BR6.LST',
'',
'1',
'L20',
'1',
'Sin 840D',
'Technika',
' ',
'St37-80',
'660.00',
'400.00',
'8.00',
'',
'',
'',
'16.58'
)
</sql>

<sql>CREATE TABLE LabelPartData</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN Count COUNTER PRIMARY KEY</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN Processed INT</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN ProgramNumber VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN ProgramRuns VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN PartNumber VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN DrawingNumber VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN DrawingName VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN Customer VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN NumberOfParts VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN DimensionX VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN DimensionY VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN Area VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN Weight VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN GeoFilename VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN BmpFilename VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN JobName VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN MaterialId VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>ALTER TABLE LabelPartData ADD COLUMN SheetSizeZ VARCHAR(255)</sql>
<sql>INSERT INTO LabelPartData ( Processed, ProgramNumber, ProgramRuns, PartNumber, DrawingNumber, DrawingName, Customer, NumberOfParts, DimensionX, DimensionY, SheetSizeZ, MaterialId, JobName, Area, Weight, GeoFilename, BmpFilename ) VALUES (0,'DOR_SHEST_BR6', '1', '1', '425900-92.08.101', '', '', '4', '377.000', '77.000', '8.00', 'St37-80', ' ', '29029.00', '1.823', 'D:\Programs TRUMPF\2015\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 (доп.1)\Крой ч10\425900-92.08.101.GEO', 'D:\эксперемент\Проба длина реза\DOR_SHEST_BR6_425900-92.08.101_1.BMP' )</sql>
<sql>INSERT INTO LabelPartData ( Processed, ProgramNumber, ProgramRuns, PartNumber, DrawingNumber, DrawingName, Customer, NumberOfParts, DimensionX, DimensionY, SheetSizeZ, MaterialId, JobName, Area, Weight, GeoFilename, BmpFilename ) VALUES (0,'DOR_SHEST_BR6', '1', '2', '425900-92.08.102', '', '', '4', '264.000', '77.000', '8.00', 'St37-80', ' ', '20328.00', '1.277', 'D:\Programs TRUMPF\2015\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 (доп.1)\Крой ч10\425900-92.08.102.GEO', 'D:\эксперемент\Проба длина реза\DOR_SHEST_BR6_425900-92.08.102_2.BMP' )</sql>


</sqlexecute>
//-->  



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, структуру данных и то, что вы хотите извлечь из  неё.

Comment: Да, извините, тоже заметил что упустил этот момент, проблемы с интернет соединением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тем, что все детали определены в одной таблице. В этом файле такая таблица находится однозначно с помощью поиска:

```
table = soup.find('table', width="600", border="1", 
                  cellspacing="1", cellpadding="0")
```

Далее можно выбрать все строки таблицы с помощью поиска

```
trs = list(table.find_all('tr'))
```

Для удобства итерации я преобразовал результат поиска в список. Использовал то, что поля в таблице идут в одном и том же порядке и в последовательных строках. Всего таких строк 15.

Осталась задача найти начало записи, после чего её уже разобрать. Начало записи обозначается строкой таблицы, содержащей строку `'НОМЕР ДЕТАЛИ:'`. Для простоты кода я использовал цикл `for`, но при желании можно использовать ручную итерацию. Возможно, она будет работать немного быстрее.

Также заметил, что на странице используются неразрывные пробелы. Они имеют код `\xa0`. Я их преобразовываю в обычные, при желании можно их убрать, на исполнение скрипта это не влияет.

Далее разбор строк. Каждая интересующая нас строка состоит из двух элементов. Первый отвечает за имя, второй -- за значение. Пробегаюсь по всем этим строкам и сохраняю почищенные значения в кортеж.

Вот полный код скрипта:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def clear_string(s):
    return s.replace('\xa0', ' ').strip()


def parse_detail(detail_rows):
    return tuple(tuple(clear_string(text) for text in row.strings)
                 for row in detail_rows)

start_row_name = 'НОМЕР ДЕТАЛИ:'
rows_count = 15

with open('File1.HTML') as in_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(in_file.read())

table = soup.find('table', width="600", border="1", 
                  cellspacing="1", cellpadding="0")
trs = list(table.find_all('tr'))


details = []
for i, tr in enumerate(trs):
    strings = tuple(clear_string(text) for text in tr.strings)
    if len(strings) == 2 and strings[0] == start_row_name:
        details.append(parse_detail(trs[i : i + rows_count]))

print(details)
```

Результат работы скрипта на представленной странице:

```
# [(('НОМЕР ДЕТАЛИ:', '1'),
#   ('НОМЕР ЧЕРТЕЖА:', '425900-92.08.101'),
#   ('ИМЯ ЧЕРТЕЖА:', ''),
#   ('ЗАКАЗЧИКА:', ''),
#   ('КОЛИЧЕСТВО:', '4'),
#   ('РАЗМЕРЫ:', '377.000 x 77.000 mm'),
#   ('ПОВЕРХНОСТЬ:', '29029.00 mm2'),
#   ('ИМЯ СВОДА ПРАВИЛ:', '5P'),
#   ('НОМЕР ПОДПРОГРАММЫ:', 'SP1DOR_SHEST_BR6 / SP3DOR_SHEST_BR6'),
#   ('ВРЕМЯ ОБРАБОТКИ:', '0.47 min (PierceLine: 0.47 min)'),
#   ('ДЛИНА РЕЗКИ:', '1241.13 mm'),
#   ('ВЕС:', '1.823 kg'),
#   ('КОЛ-ВО ТОЧЕК ВРЕЗАНИЯ:', '1'),
#   ('ВРЕМЯ ВРЕЗАНИЯ', '0.17 (PierceLine: 0.06) s'),
#   ('ИМЯ ГЕОМ. ФАЙЛА:',
#    'D:\\Programs TRUMPF\\2015\\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 '
#    '(доп.1)\\Крой ч10\\425900-92.08.101.GEO')),
#  (('НОМЕР ДЕТАЛИ:', '2'),
#   ('НОМЕР ЧЕРТЕЖА:', '425900-92.08.102'),
#   ('ИМЯ ЧЕРТЕЖА:', ''),
#   ('ЗАКАЗЧИКА:', ''),
#   ('КОЛИЧЕСТВО:', '4'),
#   ('РАЗМЕРЫ:', '264.000 x 77.000 mm'),
#   ('ПОВЕРХНОСТЬ:', '20328.00 mm2'),
#   ('ИМЯ СВОДА ПРАВИЛ:', '5P'),
#   ('НОМЕР ПОДПРОГРАММЫ:', 'SP2DOR_SHEST_BR6 / SP4DOR_SHEST_BR6'),
#   ('ВРЕМЯ ОБРАБОТКИ:', '0.42 min (PierceLine: 0.42 min)'),
#   ('ДЛИНА РЕЗКИ:', '1023.53 mm'),
#   ('ВЕС:', '1.277 kg'),
#   ('КОЛ-ВО ТОЧЕК ВРЕЗАНИЯ:', '1'),
#   ('ВРЕМЯ ВРЕЗАНИЯ', '0.17 (PierceLine: 0.06) s'),
#   ('ИМЯ ГЕОМ. ФАЙЛА:',
#    'D:\\Programs TRUMPF\\2015\\№101 Крой изделия 425901-92.00.010-10 '
#    '(доп.1)\\Крой ч10\\425900-92.08.102.GEO'))]
```

Comment: Благодарю, именно это и требовалось сделать! Ещё раз спасибо, буду разбираться, после данного опыта интерес к парсингу возрос. :)